# Proof of $x$ is divisible by $11$, if $x^2$ is divisible by $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How to prove that $11\mid x$ if  $11\mid x^2$ ? Is it enough to say that $11$ is just a prime number?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! You should mention *Euclid's lemma*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's enough. One of the basic properties of prime numbers is that $p|ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. For your example just let $a=b=x$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the name (Euclid's lemma) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of this is: is $11$ a square? Since $11$ divides a square number, namely $x^2$, then if it is a square itself, it's square root may, or may not divide $x$.

We see that since $11$ is not a square, and $11\mid x^2$, what this really tells us is that $11^2\mid x^2$ and so we must have $11\mid x$.